# MongoDB killOp() not killing the op. What do I do?

Tags: mongodb

```
> db.currentOp().inprog.length
11587
```

Several minutes later, the count is still the same. I made a small script to cycle through and `killOp()` all the ops that originated from the offending client, but when it finishes, all of the ops are still running.

I then tried a single killOp() and checked the op count and it was the same. I tried killing 10 ops, then checking the op count and it still hand't changed.

Most of the queries are all on the same table, which has over 20 million documents. The client generating all the queries has been terminated but I can't call `getIndexes()` to see if there's an indexing misconfiguration on the table because that call just goes on the end of the op queue and never returns.

We're running MongoDB on a single Linux server. There's no replication in place at this point.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know which op is that? Check mongod log to see whether it moves or has any error message. If you don't see any progress, I would suggest you to restart mongod (don't kill -9, normal kill should be ok).